# Is the helpers included in dust-full-1.2.0.js?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, helper, dust.js

I thought the helpers was included in the dust-full-1.2.0.js file but I get errors when I tried to use one :

With : `{@select key=P_Brand} Ok {/select}`

From console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined  -  dust-full-1.2.0.js:523

And with : `{@if cond="{P_Brand}"} Ok {/if}`

From console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'if' of undefined  -  dust-full-1.2.0.js:523

Is it included ? Or maybe I used them wrong...

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helpers are not included in dust-full or dust-core. They are available here: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers